# Is it appropriate to use NearestNeighbors.fit on a test dataset for graph edge generation?

Tags: python, graph, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to use the [NearestNeighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) class from scikit-learn to calculate the nearest neighbors in my data and form edges for a graph. I have separate training and test datasets and wonder whether it would cause the data leakage if I '`fit`' the model on my test set.

Here's what my approach looks like:

```
# Training phase
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=3, algorithm='brute').fit(X_train)
distances_train, indices_train = nbrs.kneighbors(X_train)

# Testing phase
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=3, algorithm='brute').fit(X_test)
distances_test, indices_test = nbrs.kneighbors(X_test)
```

I will use the `distances_test` and `indices_test` for edge information.

I am applying `fit` and `neighbors` to the test set independently of the training set because I want to form a graph for each separate dataset and I've been thinking it is okay to find the k-neighbors with brute force is not a kind of data leakage.  However, I am slightly confused and concerned about whether this could be considered data leakage, as I am using the test data in the fit process, even though I am not using this model later for any prediction task.